# how to install dctmruby on windows (access documentum with ruby)

Tags: ruby, documentum

I'm trying to use `ActiveDCTM` to access `Documentum` on windows. There are two relevant gems: `activedctm` and `dctmruby`.

When I install `dctmruby`, error occurs:

```
checking for dmAPIInit() in -ldmcl40... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
        --with-dctm-dir
        --without-dctm-dir
        --with-dctm-include
        --without-dctm-include=${dctm-dir}/include
        --with-dctm-lib
        --without-dctm-lib=${dctm-dir}/lib
        --with-myflag-dir
        --with-myflag-include
        --without-myflag-include=${myflag-dir}/include
        --with-myflag-lib
        --without-myflag-lib=${myflag-dir}/lib
        --with-dmcl40lib
        --without-dmcl40lib
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler
 failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link
0'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:476:in `try_link
'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:619:in `try_func
'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:845:in `block in
 have_library'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in
 checking_for'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2
 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in
 postpone'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone
'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking
_for'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:840:in `have_lib
rary'
        from extconf.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone know how to resolve it or is there another better way to access documentum for ruby?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Never accessed dctm with Ruby however it almost certainly needs access to the dmcl40 (a c-based library) and possibly the dfc (a java based library). Out of interest what version of documentum are you connecting to?

Comment: Just checked out this: http://www.xaop.com/blog/2010/04/21/getting-started-with-activedctm/

Comment: I have downloaded the gem from this website, however it doesn't work.

Comment: Their website suggests that it doesn't support dctm 6.x unfortunately. There was a major change in client library architecture between D5.x and D6.0, affected some of the tools I wrote for Documentum systems and I had to rearchitect them. It may work if you can get hold of dmcl40.dll from Documentum (the 5.3 version)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will have a try. Do you know other ways to access documentum for ruby?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you take a look at Documentum Foundation Services (DFS) if you can't find any way to make this work.  DFS is SOAP-based so you won't need any local libraries or older versions of packages.  I'll caveat it that all of my experience using it has been with Java or .Net, though, which both had productivity layers included vs. using raw SOAP calls.

You may also want to check out http://developer.emc.com if you haven't yet.